# Git won't push recent commits to github

Tags: git, github

I have got a local repository with about 60 commits. At about the 20th commit I pushed the project to a github repository.

My local commit history line (git log --oneline):

```
5cbd92c (HEAD -> master) Aflevering 70
fafeabb Aflevering 69
3ead1e4 Aflevering 67
37cb1b3 Aflevering 47
a8aab19 Aflevering 46
1cc0b4b Aflevering 44
4301621 Aflevering 43
353a626 Aflevering 34
2f42859 Aflevering 32
0027fc5 Aflevering 29
21eadaa Aflevering 28
be4226a (origin/master, master) Aflevering 20
6b6c5fe Aflevering 16
41c4426 Aflevering 12
0737348 Aflevering 10
```

I would expect that with

```
git push origin master
```

my whole master branch would be pushed to github. But instead the response is

```
Everything up to date
```

and nothing is uploaded to github.

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards,

Hubert

Edit: here's what `git for-each-ref` dumps out after some poking around, with `od -bc` to expose any bad characters:

```
bash$ git for-each-ref | od -bc
0000000 065 143 142 144 071 062 143 143 144 070 143 071 141 067 070 143
         5   c   b   d   9   2   c   c   d   8   c   9   a   7   8   c
0000020 061 146 143 060 146 070 061 062 067 070 141 066 070 063 063 145
         1   f   c   0   f   8   1   2   7   8   a   6   8   3   3   e
0000040 060 143 063 060 067 067 144 067 040 143 157 155 155 151 164 011
         0   c   3   0   7   7   d   7       c   o   m   m   i   t   \t
0000060 162 145 146 163 057 150 145 141 144 163 057 142 141 143 153 165
         r   e   f   s   /   h   e   a   d   s   /   b   a   c   k   u
0000100 160 012 142 145 064 062 062 066 141 063 062 064 071 066 064 144
         p   \n  b   e   4   2   2   6   a   3   2   4   9   6   4   d
0000120 146 141 146 063 062 071 071 067 065 063 145 141 144 061 070 145
         f   a   f   3   2   9   9   7   5   3   e   a   d   1   8   e
0000140 060 061 062 064 063 065 143 061 067 143 040 143 157 155 155 151
         0   1   2   4   3   5   c   1   7   c       c   o   m   m   i
0000160 164 011 162 145 146 163 057 150 145 141 144 163 057 155 141 163
         t   \t  r   e   f   s   /   h   e   a   d   s   /   m   a   s
0000200 164 145 162 012 065 143 142 144 071 062 143 143 144 070 143 071
         t   e   r   \n  5   c   b   d   9   2   c   c   d   8   c   9
0000220 141 067 070 143 061 146 143 060 146 070 061 062 067 070 141 066
         a   7   8   c   1   f   c   0   f   8   1   2   7   8   a   6
0000240 070 063 063 145 060 143 063 060 067 067 144 067 040 143 157 155
         8   3   3   e   0   c   3   0   7   7   d   7       c   o   m
0000260 155 151 164 011 162 145 146 163 057 150 145 141 144 163 057 164
         m   i   t   \t  r   e   f   s   /   h   e   a   d   s   /   t
0000300 145 163 164 012 142 145 064 062 062 066 141 063 062 064 071 066
         e   s   t   \n  b   e   4   2   2   6   a   3   2   4   9   6
0000320 064 144 146 141 146 063 062 071 071 067 065 063 145 141 144 061
         4   d   f   a   f   3   2   9   9   7   5   3   e   a   d   1
0000340 070 145 060 061 062 064 063 065 143 061 067 143 040 143 157 155
         8   e   0   1   2   4   3   5   c   1   7   c       c   o   m
0000360 155 151 164 011 162 145 146 163 057 162 145 155 157 164 145 163
         m   i   t   \t  r   e   f   s   /   r   e   m   o   t   e   s
0000400 057 157 162 151 147 151 156 057 155 141 163 164 145 162 012 065
         /   o   r   i   g   i   n   /   m   a   s   t   e   r   \n  5
0000420 143 142 144 071 062 143 143 144 070 143 071 141 067 070 143 061
         c   b   d   9   2   c   c   d   8   c   9   a   7   8   c   1
0000440 146 143 060 146 070 061 062 067 070 141 066 070 063 063 145 060
         f   c   0   f   8   1   2   7   8   a   6   8   3   3   e   0
0000460 143 063 060 067 067 144 067 040 143 157 155 155 151 164 011 162
         c   3   0   7   7   d   7       c   o   m   m   i   t   \t  r
0000500 145 146 163 057 162 145 155 157 164 145 163 057 157 162 151 147
         e   f   s   /   r   e   m   o   t   e   s   /   o   r   i   g
0000520 151 156 057 164 145 163 164 012 142 145 064 062 062 066 141 063
         i   n   /   t   e   s   t   \n  b   e   4   2   2   6   a   3
0000540 062 064 071 066 064 144 146 141 146 063 062 071 071 067 065 063
         2   4   9   6   4   d   f   a   f   3   2   9   9   7   5   3
0000560 145 141 144 061 070 145 060 061 062 064 063 065 143 061 067 143
         e   a   d   1   8   e   0   1   2   4   3   5   c   1   7   c
0000600 040 143 157 155 155 151 164 011 162 145 146 163 057 162 145 155
             c   o   m   m   i   t   \t  r   e   f   s   /   r   e   m
0000620 157 164 145 163 057 157 162 151 147 151 156 062 057 155 141 163
         o   t   e   s   /   o   r   i   g   i   n   2   /   m   a   s
0000640 164 145 162 012
         t   e   r   \n
0000644
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, per (my) question edit based on conversation ... this is most peculiar and you seem to have hit a bug in Git, as `git for-each-ref` shows only *one* `master` branch, despite your `git log` output, which shows *two* `master` branches.

The actual branch name holds `be4226a...`, which explains the `git push` result.  But nothing explains the `HEAD -> master` at `5cbd92c...`.  You do have two branch names now (`backup` and `test`) that remember *this* commit.  Depending on where and how the bug is manifesting, the following sequence *may* work to fix the problem:

```
$ git checkout backup
$ git branch -d master
$ git branch master
$ git checkout master
$ git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master
```

At this point, `git log --oneline` should show `HEAD -> master` on commit `5cbd92c` and `git push origin master` should work.

[Original answer below.]

---

Your output shows two branches named `master`:

> ```
> 5cbd92c (HEAD -> master) Aflevering 70
> ```

and:

> ```
> be4226a (origin/master, master) Aflevering 20
> ```

Now, it's not possible to have two branches with the same name,<sup>1</sup> so one of these must actually be some *other* name that simply *looks like* `master`.  For `git push` to behave the way it does, the one named `master` must be the second one, that's even with `origin/master`; the *current* branch, as indicated by `HEAD -> master` at commit `5cbd92c`, must be the one whose name *looks like* `master` but isn't actually `master` (perhaps it's `mas<invisible-character>ter` or something along those lines: if you're on a Linux system, use `git branch | cat -v` or `git for-each-ref refs/heads | od -bc` or similar).

---

<sup>1</sup>Unless you've somehow found a bug in Git, which is rare but not unheard-of.

Comment: According to the Pro Git book, origin/master indictaes the HEAD of the remote repository on the last time my local repo connected to the remote repo.

Comment: Yes. So? Commit `be4226a` has two names: `origin/master` (`refs/remotes/origin/master` to put it in full), and `master` (`refs/heads/master` in full). The problem is this other name, which looks like but isn't actually `master`, that is the branch you're on now.

Comment: But what should I do now to enable pushing the whole branch to Github?

Comment: Rename or delete one of the two branches (the "real" `master`, the one that points to commit `be4226a`). Then rename the current branch to `master` so that it's the *real* `master`. Then you'll have just one branch visibly named `master`, pointing to the correct commit, and `git push` will work. To do this you'll need to find out what the *actual* name is, despite the apparently invisible character(s) in it.

Comment: That's why I suggested using `cat -v` or `od -bc` on Linux. If you're not on Linux, find something similar for whatever you *are* on.

Comment: I am using bash. Git branch|cat -v or git log --oneline|cat -v don't give me any clues of invisible characters!

Comment: `od` or `hexdump` are better at this, and it's possible you've found a bug in Git (and/or created a file named `.git/master` somehow). The `for-each-ref` method will be better for diagnostics: you could use `git for-each-ref` without any arguments to dump all refs.

Comment: If I use git for-each-ref|cat -v, there is no indication of an invisible character. If I user git for-each-ref|od I get a screen full of hex-code that doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239795/discussion-between-torek-and-hubert1957).

Comment: I have been reading the Git Pro book a bot more and now recognize what you meant with the 2 masters. The recipe you gave to fix the problem did the trick to sole my problem. Thanx for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked. Still puzzled as to how Git got itself messed up like that. The reference "database" code in Git is a mess, and is undergoing a long-needed but long-running overhaul (I think it's been several years now)...